Three.js Text Geometry not showing
I have been trying and googling but I can't find where the problem is with my code.
I have an Angular project in which I am using Three.js for some animations. Just basic simple 2D animations.
Based on an array of numbers I am creating some squares and I want to put those numbers in the center of the squares, but these numbers (text) aren't showing.
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.canvas = this.canvasRef.nativeElement;
    this.setCanvasDimensions();

    this.sizes = {
      width: this.canvas.width,
      height: this.canvas.height
    };

    this.setup();

    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    this.afterViewInitExecuted = true;
  }

  setup(): void {
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, this.sizes.width / this.sizes.height);
    this.camera.position.z = 20;

    this.light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 70, 100);
    this.light.position.set(0, 10, 10);
    this.scene.add(this.light);

    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: this.canvas});
    this.renderer.setSize(this.sizes.width, this.sizes.height);
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(2)
    this.renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
  }

  private setCanvasDimensions(): void {
    this.canvas.width = this.canvas.parentElement.clientWidth;
    this.canvas.height = this.canvas.parentElement.clientHeight;
  }

drawRectangle(index: number, number: number): void {
    const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(this.rectWidth, this.rectWidth);
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff }));

    const bordersLength = this.arrayData.length * this.rectWidth + (this.arrayData.length + 1) * this.borderPadding;
    const X = -bordersLength / 2 + (this.borderPadding + this.rectWidth / 2) + index * (this.rectWidth + this.borderPadding);
    const Y = -(this.rectWidth / 2 + this.borderPadding);

    mesh.position.setX(X);
    mesh.position.setY(Y);
    this.sqArr.push(mesh);
    this.scene.add(mesh);

    // Draw Rectangle Borders
    this.drawRectangleBorders(geometry, X, Y);

    // Add the number in the center of the rectangle
    const loader = new FontLoader();
    loader.load('assets/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', (font) => {
      const textGeometry = new TextGeometry(number.toString(), {
        font: font,
        size: 10,
        height: 1
      });
      const textMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x000000, opacity: 1 });
      const textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, textMaterial);

      // Calculate text bounding box and position
      textGeometry.computeBoundingBox();
      const textWidth = textGeometry.boundingBox?.max.x - textGeometry.boundingBox?.min.x;
      const textHeight = textGeometry.boundingBox?.max.y - textGeometry.boundingBox?.min.y;

      if (textWidth !== undefined && textHeight !== undefined) {
        textMesh.position.set(X - textWidth / 2, Y + textHeight / 2, 0);
      } else {
        console.error('Failed to compute text bounding box.');
      }

      this.scene.add(textMesh);
    }, undefined, (error) => {
      console.error('Failed to load font:', error);
    });
  }

I made sure that the font is loading - tried it when it is online or as a file on the server.
I have double checked the light and the camera positioning, but I do not see any issues there.
I have tinkered with the size of the text and it's positioning, but no success with that.
I have also tried to check if the square is on top of the text by the Z axis, but still nothing.
